# Obtener el texto de un elemento conociendo su clase

Tags: c#, windows-forms, navegador-web

Esto es lo que encuentro en la web:

```
<span class="class1">30</span>
```

Cómo puedo obtener `30` si ya sé el valor `class1` **automáticamente**? (sin tener que esperar a que cargue para darle la orden)

Funciona una vez y por algún motivo no vuelve a funcionar. Hasta que cambio de clase y vuelve a funcionar solo una vez. Este es mi código:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Brow.Navigate("website.com");
        Brow.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(Dothing);
    }

    private void Dothing (object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {        
        foreach (HtmlElement element in Brow.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span"))
        {
            if (element.GetAttribute("class")/*I tried "classname" too*/.Equals("class1"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(element.innerHTML);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: El resultado es el mismo, sigue funcionando pero solo la primera vez.

Comment: Si,como te dije en principio debe ser el mismo efecto, era una cuestión mas de estilo :). Has probado a depurar el código, poniendo un punto de ruptura en esa línea para ver que es lo que pasa?

Comment: Has probado con `classname` o con `className`? Creo que es caseSensitive, si no lo has probado de la segunda forma, pruébalo y me comentas los resultados, a ver si varían en algo o sigue teniendo el mismo comportamiento indeseado.

Comment: Nop, sigue funcionando igual.